# How do I force functions to execute in a specific order with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make use of jQuery smooth-scrolling in case users cannot make use of the "smooth-scrolling" CSS feature, however the effect does not work when using the "scroll-snapping" effect in CSS, so I need to disable that effect when the link is clicked, execute the smooth scrolling animation, then reactivate the scroll-snapping when it is complete.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

I understand that jQuery can be used to manipulate CSS, so where do I put additional code to achieve the desired effect? The scroll-snapping is activated as part of my body CSS. The code currently functions as intended when scroll-snapping is manually disabled.

Comment: In your handler, try ``$(this).css({'scroll-behavior': 'auto'})`` to change the scrolling behavior. Replace ``auto``with the value of your choice.

Comment: I know I can manipulate CSS, but I think need to do so in a specific order, and I don't know what that order is.

Comment: Your click handler is only a few lines long. Try putting it in various places and see what happens.